# How can I match strings precisely and avoid false matches?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

Background - web app back end javascript/dojo code.

I need to match a user input string to a list of possible vehicle models and I am having challenges with incorrect matches.

Say a user enters:

```
Ford Fusion, S 60, and Volks Wagen
```

Currently, I would read that in as

```
FORDFUSIONS60VOLKSWAGEN
```

and in that, I would match against a list of makes and models.

Problem is, in this case and in many others, you get things like `"S6" (Audi) "` and `"S60" (Volvo)`, or `"Accord" (Honda)` or `"CC" (Volkswagen)`.

Any idea how it would be possible (if at all) to avoid these ambiguous matches?

Comment: Maybe this shouldn't be a free text field?

Comment: If it were up to me. Trying to allow the customer to be "flexible" and just type in whatever. For all I know they could type in "My piece of **** Hondi Accords"

Comment: You're creating too much workload for yourself and your application in trying to do that for exactly the reason your example shows. What's a *Hondi*? Did you mean Honda? Kind of sounds like Hyundai? Separate it into Make/Model - it'll save you all kinds of headaches

Comment: I am not the one to make the UI/UX decision. I have to implement it as a free-text field, unfortunately.

Comment: In that case, your requirement stretches far beyond the capabilities of regular expressions. You should investigate Full Text searching against your database provider of choice

Comment: Why would you read it as FORDFUSIONS60VOLKSWAGEN? I think you should use ponctuation, split the input correctly and then in your query you might use something like MySQL fulltext-search (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) to get the best match. Otherwise you will be searching for diffrent things than your user. :)

Comment: could you not run checks with the name, model and company and if they trace back to the same reference, then you know you have what you want. However, if you get different results keep trying combinations of all search results until they match up to a single reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is tagged [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), I think you are looking for the [word boundary metacharacter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
/\bS6\b/
```

will match `"S6"` and `"… S6 …"`, but not `"S60"`, just as

```
/\bCC\b/i
```

will match `"CC"` and `"cc"`, but not `"Accord"`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid at least the both examples you would first match against the longer names (e.g. for "s60" before "s6" and "accord" before "cc") and if there's no match, then use the shorter one. Otherwise exit with the longer one.

As far as you're looking for the longest matches, you also could check, if one of the resulting names is contained within another and skip them.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it:

Run checks with the name, model and company and if they trace back to the same reference, then you know you have what you want. However, if you get different results keep trying combinations of all search results until they match up to a single reference.

For example:
`model traces back to honda and ford,`
`number traces back to ford and bentley,`
and
`company gives ford`

then you can try combinations of list_1, list_2, and list_3 where:
`list_1 = ['honda','ford']`
`list_2 = ['ford','bentley']`
`list_3 = ['ford']`

Then when you try all combinations (I recommend `itertools.combinations`) you will end up with one valid result that is common in all lists: `ford`

I hope that is clear. I know I'm blabbing a bit.